# REST API POST endpoint that doesn't persist created resource

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, api-design, restful-url

I have a REST API in which I would like to add an endpoint that runs an algorithm and returns a result. Let's assume the algorithm is fast enough that this can be done synchronously. However, the result can be large.

**Option A**

I treat the result of the algorithm as a "resource". I could implement the following

POST /api/my-result

This creates a new result by running the algorithm. The inputs to the algorithm are in the request body. The response contains the id or some other identifiable representation of the result.

GET /api/my-result//?view=table

This allows the client to get a table representation of the result. Similarly there could be additional views, filters, etc. that could be implemented the same way.

However, this requires me to persist the results in a database. There are two issues: (a) the results can be large, and (b) the client often runs the algorithm several times with different inputs before deciding to "keep" one of the results - so ideally I only want to store the final result in the database.

**Option B**

POST /api/my-algorithm/
This accepts the parameters of the algorithm in the request body and returns the result in the response body

POST /api/my-result-table-view
This accepts the result in the request body and returns a response that transforms the representation of the result into a table view. The reason it is not GET /api/my-result//?view=table is because the client needs to be able to call this on results that are not persisted. The "table view of the result" is the resource that is created here.

Similarly, I could implement each view of the result as a separate endpoint.

POST /api/my-result
This creates a new result (without running the algorithm). For example, if the result is an image, this POST request may accept the image as a file upload and simply store it. The client calls POST /api/my-algorithm/ repeatedly, and when they are happy with the result, they call this endpoint to create the result.

I believe Option A is the more "RESTful" way, but with the overhead of persisting all results.

Which option do you recommend? Can Option B be implemented differently to make it more "RESTful"? Is there a way I can create a resource without actually persisting it in the database (maybe in a cache)? If you propose the caching route, please include more explanation as I'm not familiar with how that would be implemented.

(If it is relevant, I'm using DRF for implementing the API)